# "Closed as off topic" Question Criteria

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Occasionally I'm confused why a question gets closed. I was just browsing around and came across this one.

[Xenserver Setup & Purchase](https://serverfault.com/questions/235404/xenserver-setup-and-purchase)

I'm just curios what qualified this one as "Off Topic" ?

Comment: Had it not been closed as off-topic it could just as easily have been closed as subjective.

Comment: Subjective I wouldn't have questioned, shopping questions should be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't vote on that, but I would have voted it as off-topic.  It would not have been because of the home-office point. If you look back at some of my other posts on meta, I tend to one of the few that argues for keeping small business and small office questions here.

I would have voted to close because it is asking for a shopping recommendation.

Shopping recommendations are a very poor fit for this site.  The are almost always extremely specific to a single person.  These questions usually have no lasting value to the community or the site.  A question a person asks to today about the best cheap server today, will be worthless in a couple weeks.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

I will not vote to close a question if you can ignore the 'home office' and the question seems like a good fit for the site.  I don't care to much about the actual environment, if it is good on-topic question aside from mentioning a small office.  If the question is badly asked, or lacks details then I will vote to close.

Comment: @Zor - I'm all for small office, but home office is a different story, IMO.

Comment: @MarkM, if the question is really good or bad, aside from that distinction, does it matter?  If you can edit out the '(home|small) office' from the question and the question is on-topic, I like to leave it.  Although I admin good questions that are on-topic and mention a home-office setting are pretty rare.

Comment: @Zor - Thanks, thats pretty much what I was looking for. I totally agree with you and MarkM on the shopping angle, I was just curious if it was the home/office angle.

Comment: @Ernie - you have to remember its a matter of opinion. Some people will vote to close when others will not. It's just a matter of where the 'trigger' point is for someone.

Comment: @Zor - That's true, I guess the feeling I get is that there aren't a ton of relevant question from a home user, since they don't face many of the same problems that an administrator at a real business would. I suppose that I probably wouldn't vote to close a relevant question about a home server that's well worded and useful. The problem is that those questions seem to be few and far between.

Comment: @Robert - I get that, I'm just curious if more questions like this could get edited and possibly turned into real questions as opposed to just getting them closed.

Comment: I never come on meta to be honest but I closed this purely because it was shopping and someone else thought so too.

Answer (score 5):

Question:

> It's going to be in my home / office

FAQ:

> and it is not about …

```
* Networking outside the professional workplace
* Running servers at home for personal use
* General personal computer troubleshooting
```

Not to mention that shopping questions generally get closed as well, since it's highly subjective.

Comment: If he had said home office, would it have still qualified as off topic?

Comment: @Ernie - I still would have voted to close it. Unless you run an entire corporation out of your home office and have an IT staff. :)